# generating a HREF depending on the current URL using PHP

Tags: php

I am new to PHP so hope this isn't too embarrassing, but also have a further different question. I'm trying to make it so that a link's HREF is generated differently depending on the page.

I.e. if the url is mysite/com/blog/, make the url ../ otherwise ../../ - so whenever I create new blog posts or pages, it will automatically chose the right URL and not create a broken 404 link.

Why does the below code not work? Is there a syntax error?

Also another question - the links on my new blog to my main website work but they link to my main website using https://www.example.com/somepage.html, and I'd rather it be like `../../somepage.html` -

is the full URL bad for my website? e.g. bad for SEO, or in analytics will it show as a bounce off my website if it was the full link and not if it was from ../ ?

thanks a million!

```html
<li><a href="<?php $blog = “/blog/”; $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; if($blog==$currentpage) {http://google.com}else{http://yahoo.com}?>">About</a></li>
```

Comment: {echo "http://google.com"} else {echo "http://yahoo.com"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. I just split out the PHP from the HTML to make it easier to read. Basically, you were just missing the quotes around the destination URL. I also added a new variable *$destination* and set it to a default value. This way you can avoid the *else* which, again, just makes it easier to read.

```
<?php
$blog = '/blog/'; 
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$destination = 'http://yahoo.com'; // This is a default

if ($blog == $currentpage) {
    $destination = 'http://google.com';
}
?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $destination; ?>">About</a>
</li>
```

**EDIT**

> Also another question - the links on my new blog to my main website
>   work but they link to my main website using
>   https://www.example.com/somepage.html, and I'd rather it be like
>   ../../somepage.html -
>
> is the full URL bad for my website? e.g. bad for SEO, or in analytics
>   will it show as a bounce off my website if it was the full link and
>   not if it was from ../ ?

What do you mean when you say,

> ../

`<a href="../somepage.html">Test</a>` VS. `<a href="mysite.com/somepage.html">Test</a>` ?

If so, then there is no difference. The browser will send the user to the same page and the HTTP request will look the same.

**EDIT #2**

> thanks for that. By ../ I mean if you consider href='../somepage.html'
>   vs href='example.com/somepage.html'; - one linking locally and one
>   sending a http request and requiring the internet to work –
>   user8758206

I think there is some confusion about what is happening when you use relative links Vs. absolute links. These are instructions for the *browser at runtime*. It does not generate an extra HTTP request (redirect) when someone clicks on the link. All else being equal, both links will produce a 200 HTTP response code from the server.

Here's a discussion - [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: thanks for that. By ../ I mean if you consider href='../somepage.html' vs  href='http://example.com/somepage.html'  - one linking locally and one sending a http request and requiring the internet to work

Comment: if what you're saying - that it doesn't adversely affect SEO or analytics etc - is true then there may actually be no need to do this anyway

Comment: also out of curiosity, if this is the case, then why doesn't every website just use the http version of the link rather than just /link ? (other than to run the site locally)

Comment: I am not an SEO expert so can't speak to all the intricacies but I have a hard time believing that SEO/bots/crawlers will apply any weight difference. That being said, the URL helpers in the large PHP frameworks I work with all output absolute URLs. My recommendation would be to use whatever is easier for you.

Comment: thanks - I've also just read that absolute and relative dont really matter that much, so I think you're right :)